# How to walk a folder under resources folder in springboot in jar file execution

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, executable-jar

My springboot application comprises of an H2 database, where in code I traverse through a folder (`rules`) inside `src/main/resources` and execute SQL statements by reading files inside `src/main/resources/rules`.

`rules` folder again has few folders inside it. My current code, which executes well when run in IntelliJ is below:

```java
private void loadDb() {
        log.info("Hello!") // this prints Hello! when executed via jar
        File rulesDir = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/rules").getFile())
        log.info("Read file: ", rulesDir) // this prints empty when run via jar
        if (rulesDir.exists() && rulesDir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] fileArr = rulesDir.listFiles()

            log.info("**********************************************")
            log.info("Files from rules directory : " + rulesDir)
            log.info("**********************************************")

            recursiveLoad(fileArr, 0)
        }
    }

    private void recursiveLoad(File[] fileArr, int level) {
        for (File f : fileArr) {
            for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
                System.out.print(TAB)

            if (f.isFile() && f.getName().substring(f.getName().indexOf(DOT) + 1) == "insert") {
                log.info(f.getName())
                executeSqlStatements(f)
            } else if (f.isDirectory()) {
                log.info("[" + f.getName() + "]")

                recursiveLoad(f.listFiles(), level + 1)
            }
        }
    }
```

So, my issue is, this above code doesn't work when executed via `JAR`. I did some research and found out that we need to read files as streams for it to work via JAR execution but I am not sure how to implement above in a way that it works in JAR execution.

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) instead? Basically you'd put your SQL files in `src/main/resources/db/migration` (default) and Flyway handles the rest.

Comment: @slauth We can consider this but for now it might not work for us as this is a very simple application we're trying to setup.

Comment: Flyway can be used in very simple applications, too :) I'd argue it would make it even simpler because you'd not need any of the code posted here.

Comment: I'll take a look. But, for now, is there any Java way of doing it?